# Variable\Property naming convention

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, naming-conventions

When im naming a variable for a directory should i end the variable name with path, folder or directory.

Im writing my code in .net..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, first some definitions:

- A **Path** is an address within the file system, it can point to either a file or a directory.
- A **Directory** can contain multiple files and subdirectories.
- A **File** can be accessed via it's full path (e.g. `C:\Temp\Foo.txt`), or a relative path (`..\Temp\Foo.txt`). (I would consider the file name (`Foo.txt`) to be a relative path as well).

Therefore, if a variable is ambiguous, (i.e. could point to either a file or a directory, like when recursively walking through the directory tree,) I would call it `FooPath`.

If your variable always points to one file, I would call it `FooFile`

If your variable is always the name of a directory, and never of a file, I would let this reflect by calling it `FooDirectory`, or `FooDir` for short.

But of course the most important rule is consistency: Choose one naming convention and stick with it. Do not call one variable `FooDirectory`, the next `BarDir` and the third `BuzzFolder`.

Answer (score 3):

I use "path" to refer to the full path of a file (directory + file name). I'd recommend "folder", "directory" or even "dir".

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter - all are more or less synonymous and should be clearly understood in context.

The only caveat I'd say is that path could be a web location or a file, where folder and directory won't be, if that helps your decision.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official coding convention for this out there.
I prefer this style:

***Path** (SystemPath, AppPath) for "C:\Windows\Systems32" or "file://..." or "../../bin/Debug"

***Dir** (ImageDir, ThemeDir) for ("img" or "theme")